# Query rows in SQL using a pivot table having an array of ids

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. One contains spouses with id, name and second_name. The other one is a pivot table that has an id of each spouse and date of marriage.

[image: Table schema]

There are 10 entries in Spouse table and 5 in Pivot table. No duplicates and no same person marriage cases.

The data looks like this:

```
Spouse:
 id | name    | second_name
 ---------------------------
 0  | Nina    | Corynn
 1  | Marc    | Brown
 2  | Alex    | Tennenbaum
 3  | Josh    | Black
 4  | Brad    | Star
 5  | Jessica | Labert
 6  | Elise   | Tamra
 7  | Callie  | Lexia
 8  | Jack    | Kimberley
 9  | Anthony | Josh

Pivot:
 left_person_id | right_person_id | date_of_marriage
 ---------------------------------------------------
 1              | 2               | 2017-05-02   
 4              | 5               | 2017-05-02   
 8              | 6               | 2017-05-02   
 9              | 7               | 2017-05-02   
 0              | 3               | 2017-05-02
```

What is the SQL query if I have an array of following ids (1*, 6* , 3*) and I want to get result like:

```
Result:
 id | name | date_of_marriage
 -------------------------------
 1* | Marc | 2017-05-02
 2  | Alex | 2017-05-02
 8  | Jack | 2017-05-02
 6* | Elise| 2017-05-02
 0  | Nina | 2017-05-02
 3* | Josh | 2017-05-02
```

(*) Please note that the result is merged in the way that the left_person_id is always before the right_person_id.

EDIT

Solution with the least queries will be accepted.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/139c6e)

Comment: If you think that this is a simple join query then feel free to post your solution.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand

Comment: Sorry then, I thought you're being sarcastic. I do not care whether you use join or inner select (or anything else). I will accept any solution that does the job.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `UNION` of `UNION`s to get the results in the expected order. E.g. Below query returns all the records by `right_person_id`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT left_person_id, date_of_marriage, @countx := @countx + 1 AS c
    FROM pivot, (SELECT @countx := 1) x
    WHERE right_person_id in (1, 6, 3)

    UNION

    SELECT right_person_id, date_of_marriage,  @county := @county + 1 AS c
    FROM pivot, (SELECT @county := 1) y 
    WHERE right_person_id in (1, 6, 3)) b
ORDER BY c
```

Similarly, you can write `left_person_id` version for the same query and `UNION` it with the above output to get the final result.

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49694c/4/0)**.

Comment: It works well but as you can see there will be only 4 rows instead of 6. The id #1 is it the left_person_id column.

Comment: Yes, as I explained in the answer, you need to `union` the `left_person_id` version of the same query to the above query, and it will return all the records.